# Jquery UI Sortable & Resizable Divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make sortable divs vertically resizable. When sortable, all contents of the class including the resize handle is being considered for the sort. Separately, the jQuery UI functions work with no problem.

I have also tried utilizing the handlers in CSS with `.ui-resizable-handle` and a div as a wrapper to my "slides", but I would believe there is a better way.

I have tried the CSS resize.
I have tried the jQUery UI resizable function on the class.

```js
$(".slides").sortable({
  placeholder: 'slide-placeholder',
  axis: "y",
  revert: 150,
  start: function(e, ui) {

    placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
    ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
    $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);

  },
  change: function(event, ui) {

    ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
      height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
    }, 300);

    placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));

    $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
      height: 0
    }, 300, function() {
      $(this).remove();
      placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
      $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    });

  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {

    $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();

  },
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.slides {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.slideBody {
  background-color: white;
}

.slides {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.slide {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide-placeholder {
  background: #DADADA;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-placeholder:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.slide2 {
  height: 30px;
}

.slide3 {
  height: 50px;
}

.slide4 {
  height: 90px;
}

.slide5 {
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide slide1">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide slide2">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide slide3">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide slide4">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="slide slide5">Slide 5</div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/sterling415/pen/MxKKvG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend jQuery UI's [Resizable Interaction](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/), in addition to the [Sortable Interaction](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

```js
$(".slides").sortable({
  axis: "y"
});

$('.slide').resizable({
  handles: 'n, s'
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.slides {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.slide {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

.slide2 {
  height: 30px;
}

.slide3 {
  height: 50px;
}

.slide4 {
  height: 90px;
}

.slide5 {
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide slide1">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide slide2">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide slide3">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide slide4">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="slide slide5">Slide 5</div>
</div>
```